# How to create horizontal and vertical listview on the same page on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I want to create a page where data will display two horizontal lists inside main vertical list. I searched many articals and i found use one listview on a single page other says don't use listview inside scrollview but i want 2-3 listview on a single page then how can I achieve that on Xamarin Forms.

Anyone can suggest me what to do?

Comment: This one helps you https://causerexception.com/2018/02/06/xamarin-forms-ultimate-horizontal-list-guide/

Comment: I believe that, if you add horizontal list inside to a vertical scrollview its ok. The same scroll's trend is the problem for user experience.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but many applications doing many scroll on the same screen like grofers one of them.

Comment: Yes , has one main vertical scrollview and more horizontal scrolls inside them.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122229/listview-scrolling-with-horizontal-and-vertical

Answer (score -1):

Xamarin `ListView` is supposed to take the whole page and has nothing underneath it and scroll vertically. Which means you can't use it. Those are your options:

- create the custom renderer that would fulfill your needs
- find some ready made component that can fulfill your needs
- try with Xamarin.Forms 4.0 (available in beta) and its `CollectionView` which seems to be able to work according to your requests
- use native views for this.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, can you suggest me any ready made component or link?